# Why "got a sore throat" but "got - hepatitis"?

Tags: grammar

I'm learning english grammar and I found some sentences that made me a bit confused.

Why "got a sore throat" but "got - hepatitis" ?

How to use "got a something" and "got something" ?

Thanks.

Comment: You may find our sister site, *English Language Learners* more helpful for this type of question.

Comment: You use "got a <st>" when a part of your body is affected. You use "got <st>" when your whole body is affected. ("Got pneumonia/cancer/leukemia/hepatitis") However, we (American English speakers) typically say, "caught a cold" and "got the flu," perhaps because they are common.

Comment: There are various duplicates or near-duplicates on ELU, for instance [a cold vs flu vs the flu](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60684/a-cold-vs-flu-the-flu), and  [Is flu the only disease usually accompanied with 'the'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360387/is-flu-the-only-disease-usually-accompanied-with-the) (where tchrist gives an impressive list of exceptions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule is that you do not use either the definite, or indefinite article with the *names* of diseases or medical conditions.

"Hepatitis" is the name of a medical condition.

"A sore throat" is *not* the name of a medical condition, it is a *description* of a *symptom*. A sore throat could be caused by a medical condition such as streptococcal pharyngitis (commonly referred to as 'strep throat).

So it is correct to say:

> I have a sore throat (symptom)
>   I have strep throat (medical condition)
>   I have a fever (symptom)
>   I have hepatitis (medical condition)

There are a few notable exceptions - "[the flu](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/flu/)" being the most common one. This is just a historic common name for influenza and has become idiomatic. Other historic names for medical conditions such as "the plague" or "the black death" are still referred to with the definite article, along with some *fictitious* "conditions" such as "the dreaded lurgy" or " the heebie-jeebies".

Further exceptions exist with "compound" words such as "[toothache](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/toothache/)" or "[headache](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/headaches/)". Idiomatically, most people say "I have **a** headache", but "I have toothache" (no article). The links to the NHS website (United Kingdom's national health service) also show these used in this way. These could be viewed as descriptions of symptoms, but also as "names" for what you are experiencing, so you should check examples to see how they are idiomatically used.

These exceptions are not an exhaustive list.

Comment: This may usually be the case, but not always.  For example, we say “I’ve got toothache”, not “I’ve got a toothache”.  We might say “I have liver disease” or “I have liver disease”.   Nevertheless you give a useful rule of thumb.

Comment: @Tuffy I did say the list of exceptions wasn't exhaustive! "Toothache" is a compound word of "tooth" and "ache", so arguably it *is* a name, unlike "sore throat". Of course, it is "a headache", but there's another potential exception.

Comment: @Tuffy I would normally call "I've got toothache" an error.  Perhaps it's a regional thing?

Comment: @Hellion The NHS website (health service for the entire United Kingdom) refers to "toothache" without an article: https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/toothache/

Comment: It must be a AmE/BrE thing.  “I’ve got toothache” sounds very wrong to me.  (AmE)

Comment: @Jim And yet Americans say "I got brain freeze"?

Comment: @Astralbee - Maybe that’s treated as a name, or maybe they only say that when their brain is frozen and therefore can’t be held responsible for what comes out.  ;-)

Comment: @Astralbee It is not unknown for the definite article to be applied to various common illnesses. Though one perhaps hears people say "he has the measles" less nowadays than one did sixty years ago. I don't think it is simply a dialect influence, but I remember it from my childhood in the 1940s - 50s. I particularly remember, as a child getting "the mumps".  Perhaps it is more usual when there is a particular epidemic in the community. I speak here for UK practice.

Comment: @WS2 I can only direct you to the last line of my answer: "These exceptions are not an exhaustive list",